# Pause an infinite CSS3 animation on hover and use transform

Tags: css, animation

Is it possible to run an animation infinitely on an element, but pause that animation and have another CSS3 transition/transform occur?

```
<div class="shake"></div>
```

For example, I have an animation -

```
@-keyframes undulate {
  0%        {  transform: translate(0,0); }
  5%        {  transform: translate(0px,-10px); }
  10%   {  transform: translate(0,0);}
  15%       {  transform: translate(0px,-10px); }
  20%   {  transform: translate(0,0);}
  100%  {  transform: translate(0,0);}
}
```

And the div I am running it on:

```
.shake {
   display:block; position:absolute;
   z-index:1000; 
   bottom:100px; left:50%;
   margin-left:-40px;
   width:80px; height:82px;
   background: #336699;
   cursor:pointer;

   -webkit-animation:undulate 3s linear 0s infinite;
   animation:undulate 3s linear 0s infinite;
}

.shake:hover {
   -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
   animation-play-state:paused; 
   transform: translate(0px,3px);
   -ms-transform:translate(0px,3px);
   -webkit-transform:translate(0px,3px);    
}
```

So, what I am attempting to accomplish is pause the animation `undulate` and then run the `transform` effect on `:hover` state.  Once the `:hover` state is over, I would like it to return to the original indefinite animation.

**http://jsfiddle.net/3R92G/ - DEMO**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `animation-play-state`, just remove the animation during the hover:

```
.shake:hover {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    animation: none;    
}
```

Setting the same property via an animation and a normal rule seems to conflict.

http://jsfiddle.net/3R92G/2/